# Create basic animation

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, runnable, thread-sleep

How can I create basic animation in Java?

Currently i am trying to implement a basic animation program using swing in Java.
  But i am not getting whether my logic for program in correct or not.
  My program implements `Runnable`, `ActionListener` interfaces and also extends `JApplet`.
  I want to know that, is it necessary to differentiate start method of JApplet and Runnable?

And if yes then why..?

My program is basic balloon program, when I click on start button balloons start moving    upward and comes to floor again. This will be continue till i press stop button.

Here is my code.

```
public class Balls extends JApplet implements Runnable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel btnPanel=new JPanel();
    static boolean flag1=true;
    static boolean flag2=true;
    static boolean flag3=false;
    static int h;
    static int temp=10;
    Thread t=new Thread(this);

    JButton start;
    JButton stop;


    public void init()
    {
         try
         {
             SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(

                 new Runnable()
                 {
                     public void run()
                     {
                         makeGUI();
                     }


                 });                         

         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Can't create GUI because of exception"); 
             System.exit(0);
         }

    }


    private void makeGUI() {

        start=new JButton("start");
        stop=new JButton("stop");
        btnPanel.add(start);
        btnPanel.add(stop);
        add(btnPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public void run()
    {           
        while(true)
        {
            if(flag1)
            {
                repaint();
                flag1=false;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    wait();
                    flag3=true;
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error ocuured !!\n Exiting..");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }   
        }   

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int h=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("height"));
        if (flag1)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(10,h,50,50);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(50,h,20,20);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.fillOval(70,h,80,30);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(120,h,50,60);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillOval(160,h,70,50);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(200,h,80,80);
            g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g.fillOval(260,h,80,30);
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillOval(320,h,60,40);
            g.setColor(Color.pink);
            g.fillOval(370,h,65,45);
            flag1=false;
        }
        else
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(10,h-temp,50,50);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(50,h-temp,20,20);
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.fillOval(70,h-temp,80,30);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(120,355,50,60);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillOval(160,h-temp,70,50);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillOval(200,h-temp,80,80);
            g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g.fillOval(260,h-temp,80,30);
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillOval(320,h-temp,60,40);
            g.setColor(Color.pink);
            g.fillOval(370,h-temp,65,45);
            if(flag2 && temp<=400)
            {
                temp+=10;
                if(temp==400)
                {
                    flag2=false;
                }
            }
            else if(!flag2)
            {
                temp-=10;
                if(temp==10)
                {
                    flag2=true;
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                t.start();
                if(flag3)
                {
                    notify();
                }

            }
        });
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                flag1=false;
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    repaint();
                    t=null;
                }
            }
        });

    }       
}
```

Comment: Usually animation in java take the use of [**`SwingTimer`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), also there are libraries. But I really didn't tried on `JApplet`, I don't know how it works on it.

Comment: http://cs.wellesley.edu/~cs111/fall05/labs/lab12/animationDemo.html Here is a link, i got the idea from this link.They have used Applet.

Comment: Very nice website with all sorts of examples

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/Animation.htm

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I don't know whether my logic is correct or not .I am just trying to implemment .I want to know what is wrong in my code.If it is incorrect then please tell me correct logic,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use [`SwingTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as recommended instead of your `Runnable` implementation.

2) Read about [custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) , [and here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#swing_summary)

3) draw at the `JPanel` instead of on `JFrame`

I have changed your code, examine it. I think, that it does what you want.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Balls extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    static boolean flag1 = true;
    static boolean flag2 = true;
    static boolean flag3 = false;
    static int h;
    static int temp = 10;
    JButton start;
    JButton stop;
    private Timer timer;

    public void init() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(

            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    makeGUI();
                }

            });
    }

    private void makeGUI() {
        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
        start = new JButton("start");
        stop = new JButton("stop");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });
        btnPanel.add(start);
        btnPanel.add(stop);
        add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel{

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
             super.paintComponent(g);
            int h = Integer.parseInt(getParameter("height"));
            if (flag1) {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(10, h, 50, 50);
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillOval(50, h, 20, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillOval(70, h, 80, 30);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillOval(120, h, 50, 60);
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillOval(160, h, 70, 50);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(200, h, 80, 80);
                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g.fillOval(260, h, 80, 30);
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.fillOval(320, h, 60, 40);
                g.setColor(Color.pink);
                g.fillOval(370, h, 65, 45);
                flag1 = false;
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillOval(10, h - temp, 50, 50);
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.fillOval(50, h - temp, 20, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillOval(70, h - temp, 80, 30);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillOval(120, 355, 50, 60);
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillOval(160, h - temp, 70, 50);
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillOval(200, h - temp, 80, 80);
                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g.fillOval(260, h - temp, 80, 30);
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.fillOval(320, h - temp, 60, 40);
                g.setColor(Color.pink);
                g.fillOval(370, h - temp, 65, 45);
                if (flag2 && temp <= 400) {
                    temp += 10;
                    if (temp == 400) {
                        flag2 = false;
                    }
                } else if (!flag2) {
                    temp -= 10;
                    if (temp == 10) {
                        flag2 = true;
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your modified code helped me to sharpen my concepts ,but still it is giving error ,Thanks for Replying.Thank you

Comment: w7, do you add imports to your class?

Comment: Hey ,I am so sorry.it works fine i got my answer ,But what was the problem with Runnable.?thanks...Thanks a lot

Comment: Read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and `SwingTimer` it's for this purposes